# Controlling map on android

Tags: android, cordova, winjs

*WP8.1* used to have `ms-appx-web`: //it works there

```
document.getElementById('IMap').navigate('ms-appx-web:///html/maps.html');
```

but in Android it does not .
So
*What is the equivalent in Android?*

I am trying to create hybrid app using *apache cordova*...